# Upload videos to IGTV in Instagram besides the 9:16 and 16:9 ratio, as some accounts have done

Tags: video, instagram

Is there a way (on cellphone, via Facebook or whatever) to upload a video in actual 4:3 ratio to IGTV in Instagram and keep that proportion everywhere (much like in regular Instagram posts), instead of having to keep it locked and cropped on 16:9 or 9:16? I had seen a couple of accounts that actually have done that (https://www.instagram.com/tv/CKMLclPjB4G/ and https://www.instagram.com/tv/CQmBImnhaMl/ , note the later is not even a verified account), yet I fear it was some kind of temporal bug, but still.